# Control Finder's window "tab-bar" visibility with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

Is there a way in Applescript to control visibility of a Finder's window "tab-bar" (don't know the english name)?

I know Applescript can get/set statusbar and toolbar visibility, but found nothing of this "tab-bar", the one that let you have multiple tabbed windows).

Comment: Check [Using Applescript to close Finder tabs](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8446928?answerId=33583655022#33583655022)

Answer (score 0):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    delay 0.1
    if not (exists of window 1) then reveal desktop
    delay 0.1
    tell its window 1
        activate
        repeat until visible
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events" to key code 17 using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```

**SIDE-NOTE:** This code will not work if your Finder window 1(Frontmost Finder Window) is open with more than one tab already opened

Comment: About your side note... Finder itself doesn't allow hiding the Tab Bar if any window has more then one tab, not just window 1. This is hardcoded and not any fault with your code

Comment: @user3439894  But in the event you have 2 Finder windows open and the Finder window 2 has two tabs but Finder window 1 has only 1, the code will work.  However if Finder window 2 has 1 tab but Finder window 1 has 2 tabs, the code will fail.  So pretty much Finder window 1's tab count will determine whether the script fails or not